# Monte Carlo Localization with Ros Hydro

Tags: rviz, turtlebot, ros-hydro, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i use my custom monte carlo localization code to localize my robot?Because i do not want to use ROS AMCL, i want to try my own localization code.Is there any source which implements monte carlo localization algorithm and uses in in ROS?

And how can i run that code on my robot?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102161/monte-carlo-localization-with-ros-hydro/) by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) is a monte carlo localization/particle filter based approach. So even if you do not want to use it, you can still look at the code to get an idea how a ROS interface for your own code could look like.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2013-11-17**:
Thanks for your quick answer.Where can i find ROS AMCL code?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-17**:
amcl is documented on the wiki at: http://wiki.ros.org/amcl as linked above. Which includes references to the source.